# How do I launch python code like a stand-alone app with a simple double click?

Tags: python, windows, macos, executable

So I'm new to coding and I'm currently learning Python with the intention of creating a basic GUI for running test software and automating equipment. What I can't seem to understand at this stage is how I will go about launching my python code. As it stands now I run my basic code from the terminal or IDE (I'm on Mac OS X), but when I have a working program with a GUI I want myself and others to be able to just click and run the program as you would any other application. Can I make it so someone could just double click the .py file and the app would run and no code or terminal would be visible, just the GUI? Or do I have to make some sort of executable file for each OS? Worth noting that eventually the final product will be running on windows xp.

Comment: where is your effort?

Comment: I assume you're asking whether I've actually tried to figure it out myself yet. Well no, I'm just asking whether its possible to achieve what I want, or am I learning the wrong language for my end goal?